# Access file in assets folder via fileinputstream(string fileName) in android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

Due to using a third party API I am stuck trying to pass a String "file path" to a method in the API in order to use the functionality of the API.

The file is a text file that contains all the configuration instructions including a set of parameters needed for the API to function. How do I programmatically get string file path of a file located in the assets folder of my apk on an android device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Due to using a third party API I am stuck trying to pass a String "file path" to a method in the API in order to use the functionality of the API.

Find a better library, one that accepts an `InputStream` or `Reader`. Feel free to point whoever created that library to [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/08/07/for-android-apis-think-streams-not-files.html) to help explain the issue.

> How do I programmatically get string file path of a file located in the assets folder of my apk on an android device?

You don't, because assets are not files on the device. They are only files on your development machine.

Your only option is to copy the content from the asset to some file that you control (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`) using standard Java I/O, then use that file with the library.

Comment: Unfortunately the API situation is out of my control. To the second point, are you suggesting I make a file on the device and copy over whats in the text file?

Comment: @BrandtSmith: Yes. It is your only option to have a file with the content from that asset. So, use `AssetManager` and `open()` to get an `InputStream` on the asset's contents, create a `FileOutputStream` on some `File`, then use Java I/O to copy between the streams. When you're done, close the `FileInputStream`, and use your `File` with the API.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been stuck on this for too long.